# C While Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, fault

Why does this throw a segmentation fault?

I have debugged my program down to this, which is giving an error? can someone explain why?

```
char code1[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
char code2[] = "bpduhijkaltxwmrzfoysvngeqc ";

void code(char *encode[]){
    char encoded[strlen(encode)];
    strcpy (encoded, encode);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (encode[i] != '\0'){
        while(encode[i] != code1[j]){
            j++;
        }
    encoded[i] = code2[j];
    i++;
    j=0;
}
i=0;
printf("The word is: %s \n", encoded);
```

}

Comment: What happens if `encode[i]` is not in `code1`? Also look into the `strchr` function

Comment: Sorry I have updated the post with the variables.

Comment: `char encoded[strlen(encode)];` needs to be`char encoded[strlen(encode) + 1];` to accomodate the NUL terminator. If you still get segmentation faults after that then please run your program in a debugger (in fact that should always be the case before turning to help from others).

Comment: Your types are wrong. The argument to `code` should have type `char*`, not `char*[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't including the null byte `'\0'` in the result string. A c-string ends with the `'\0'` character which is not included in the length:

```
char encoded[strlen(encode)+1];
strcpy(encoded, encode);
```

Also you need to check to make sure that every character in `encode` is also in `code1`, otherwise you'll access data outside of `code`. You can add a check for `code1[j] == '\0'` and skip that character. You should also look at the `strchr` function to search for the character instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm still getting the error with that change though.

Comment: Do you know where exactly the crash is happening? Run the code through a debugger.

Comment: debugger is pointing to this line: while(encode[i] != code1[j]){

Comment: Are you including the check that the character is found in `code1`?

Answer (score 0):

This runs but does not work the way you expected. Problem is in encoding decoding and that is another question !

```
char code1[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
char code2[] = "bpduhijkaltxwmrzfoysvngeqc ";
char code3[99]={0};    

void code( char *encode[] )
{
  char encoded[strlen( encode )];
  strcpy( encoded, encode );
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while ( encode[i] != '\0' )
  {
    while ( encoded[i] != code1[j] )  // encoded not encode
    {
      j++;
    }
    encoded[i] = code2[j];
    i++;
    j = 0;
  }
  i = 0;
  printf( "The word is: %s \n", encoded );

}

int main(  )
{
  strcpy( code3 , "once upon a time there was a lost coder");
  code( code3 );
}
```

Comment: It works when I use code1, but when i try to use a random string i get a segmentation fault still, E.G: char cat[] = "The cat sat";     Thanks for the help good spot btw

Comment: What exactly does this solution solve? This still has the same problem as the original code.

Comment: This solution solves the original question : segmentation fault. It runs, the original didn't. Now, there is another problem.

Comment: No it doesn't: `char encoded[strlen( encode )];`. See my answer